# Swift: Checking UISwitch on mode by regarding other UISwitch's status

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have more than one UISwitch on the same view. On my form, I need to use UISwitch like radio button (web). No more than one UISwitch can be **on** at he same time, I need just one.

If a UISwitch turning on, I want to check others and if there are any UISwitch with on mode, need to turn it off. Is it possible?

I can check it in a button action but, I want to change UISwitch status real time.

**UPDATE AFTER SOLVED:**

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var secondSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func firstSwitchAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.secondSwitch.on == true {
        self.secondSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func secondSwitchAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.firstSwitch.on == true {
        self.firstSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create outlets for your switches, you can change them with the .setOn method

A quick example

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var myOtherSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func mySwitchTouched(sender: UISwitch) {

    if sender.on == true {

        myOtherSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)

    }
}
```